# React redirect on error avoiding code duplication

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I have a graphql function where it checks if request token has expired, if it is expired I need it to redirect to login. On each page of my app, I make a call the the server for some data and if there is an error I need to redirect to login. I need to eliminate the code reusage here and I need some help.

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: ApolloLink.from([
    onError(({ graphQLErrors, operation, forward }) => {
      if (graphQLErrors) {
        graphQLErrors.forEach(err => {
          // handle errors differently based on its error code
          switch (err.extensions.code) {
            case 'INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR':
              // This is the case when the user session expires
              if (err.path && err.path[0] === 'updateToken') {
                removeItem(AUTH_TOKEN);
                history.push('/login');
              }
              return forward(operation);
            default:
              return forward(operation);
          }
        });
      }
    }),
  ]),  
});
```

On each page on my app I make a request to the graphql client,

```
const Profiles = () => {
  // Omitted code
  const { loading, error, data, refetch, fetchMore } = useQuery(
    GET_PROFILES(),
    {
      variables: { id },
    }
  );

  if (loading) {
    return <Loading />;
  }

  if (error) {
    // I need to find a way to eliminate this line because I am duplicating it on every page of my app
    if (error.message === '403: Forbidden' || error.message === '401: Unauthorized') {
      return <Redirect to="/login" />;
    }

    return <Alert message="Error" description="Failed to load profiles." type="error" showIcon />;
  }

  return (
    <div>OMITTED</div>
  );
};
```

On every page of my app I have the same error if statement. I need to remove the line where I check error message because I duplicate it on every page of my app. I was thinking maybe I can do something on `case 'INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR':` case.

I dont want to show the alert if those errors are true

Comment: no forward on failure?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/63806405/6124657 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Higher Order Component:

```
const WithQuery = (Comp, query, getVariables) => (props) => {
  const { loading, error, data, refetch, fetchMore } = useQuery(
    query(),
    {
      variables: getVariables(),
    }
  )

  if (loading) {
    return <Loading />;
  }

  if (error) {
    // I need to find a way to eliminate this line because I am duplicating it on every page of my app
    if (error.message === '403: Forbidden' || error.message === '401: Unauthorized') {
      return <Redirect to="/login" />;
    }

    return <Alert message="Error" description="Failed to load profiles." type="error" showIcon />;
  }

  return <Comp {...props} data={data} />
}

const Profiles = WithQuery(({ data, name }) => {
  return (
    <div>OMITTED</div>
  );
}, GET_PROFILES, () => ({ id }));

// usage
<Profiles name="Test Name" />
```

Comment: This is what I am looking for! How can I access the data variable within the profiles component?

Comment: Also do you know where I can find more information on how to do this with graphql?

Comment: I've edited the code for you to be able to access the data variable

Comment: Can you also show how to pass props to Profiles component?

Comment: `const Profiles = ({ names }) = WithQuery(({ data }) => { `  doesnt seem to work